# How to reposition image in ImageBackground React Native?

Tags: react-native, image, react-native-stylesheet, imagebackground, object-position

I have a big image that I'm using in the React Native `ImageBackground` component.

```js
function Component(){
  return <ImageBackground style={{
    height: 300,
    width: '100%',
  }}/>;
}
```

The size is correct, but I would like to reposition the image internally as in [`object-position` in css](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-position). What is an equivalent style selector?

Comment: You will have to handle it with padding. No other option.

Comment: @AlapAnerao How will I do that? If I dont specify dimensions, the image is way too big. If I do set `width:'100%'`, then the image is already cut off.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `resizeMode` prop of Image. ImageBackground inherits app the properties of Image. Setting correct image resizeMode should resolve your issuel.
Refer this : https://reactnative.dev/docs/image#resizemode